# Show that if A is strictly diagonal dominant, then a submatrix of A is also strictly diagonal dominant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

In this problem, the submatrix of A is A2. A2 is the submatrix that forms after apply Gaussian elimination to the first column of A, so A2 is the submatrix that excludes row 1 and column 1 of A after Gaussian elimination.

Clarification:The matrix it's referring to is A2. A2 was created after Gaussian elimination was applied to only the first column of A. So this yields.the matrix [a11 a1^t; 0 A2]. a1^t is the rest of the first row. Everything below a11 in column 1 is zero. Then A2 is the submatrix.

Comment: Which submatrix? Certainly not all submatrices, I presume.

Comment: The matrix it's referring to is A2. A2 was created after Gaussian elimination was applied to only the first column of A. So this yields.the matrix [a11 a1^t; 0 A2]. a1^t is the rest of the first row. Everything below a11 in column 1 is zero. Then A2 is the submatrix.

Comment: Think about the relation between the entries of $A$ and $A2$. I think they are related by a scalar, so that preserves strict diagonal dominance.